# python codes questions for llvm

Tags: spyder

when i running following codes in spyder, meet error:
start IPython error
**LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __powidf2**

- Spyder version: 4.2.1 None
- Python version: 3.8.3 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.12.10
- PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
- Operating System: Windows 10

codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from financepy.finutils import *
from financepy.products.bonds.FinBond import *

#Define the Bond
issueDate = FinDate(15, 5, 2020)
maturityDate = FinDate(15, 5, 2030)
coupon = 0.050 # This means 5%
freqType = FinFrequencyTypes.ANNUAL
accrualType = FinDayCountTypes.ACT_ACT_ICMA
faceAmount = ONE_MILLION
bond = FinBond(issueDate, maturityDate, coupon, freqType, accrualType, faceAmount)
print(bond)
```

but when i run the codes in VS code, it's good with following results:

OBJECT TYPE: FinBond
ISSUE DATE: 15-MAY-2020
MATURITY DATE: 15-MAY-2030
COUPON: 0.05
FREQUENCY: FinFrequencyTypes.ANNUAL
ACCRUAL TYPE: FinDayCountTypes.ACT_ACT_ICMA
FACE AMOUNT: 1000000

**My question is**, how to fix the problem in spyder ? many thanks